# Hide sidebar only product detail page on mobile

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to hide the sidebar on product page when the visitor is on mobile. Any idea how to achieve it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it with responsive css.

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px){
   .sidebar_class { display:none }
}
```

add "sidebar_class" to sidebar main div or replace .sidebar_class with your sidebar main class in above CSS.

you can find media query details from below referenc
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile